# Read & Print File From Menu Selection

Tags: java, file, netbeans, console-application, java.util.scanner

I am trying to complete my in course assessment (ICA) for JAVA 1 & am struggling to read & print the contents of a text (.txt) file from my console application in NetBeans 8.0.2.

The program displays a menu with 5 options. I am trying to complete option 4 which reads the text file & prints out all information on each contract on separate lines.

so far I have:

```
package contractmanager;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;      //  for FileNotFoundException
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Menu {
    boolean exit;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Menu menu = new Menu();
    menu.runMenu();
 }

 public void runMenu(){
     while(!exit){
         printMenu();
         int choice = getInput();
         performAction(choice);
     }
 }

private void printMenu(){
    System.out.println("1. Enter New Contract");
    System.out.println("2. Display Smmary of Contracts");
    System.out.println("3. Display Summar1y of Contracts for Selected Month");
    System.out.println("4. Find And Display Contract");
    System.out.println("0. Exit");
}

private int getInput (){
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = -1;
    while(choice < 0 || choice  > 4){
        try {
            System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
            choice = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again");
        }
    }
    return choice;
}

private void performAction(int choice){
    switch(choice){
        case 0:
            exit = true;
            System.out.println("Thank you for using this application");
            break;
        case 1:
            enterContract();
            break;
        case 2:
            displaySummary();
            break;
        case 3:
            displayMonth();
            break;
        case 4:
            findContract();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("An unknown error has occured");
    }
}

private void enterContract() {
     System.out.println("Please enter the client name: ");
     Scanner cName = new Scanner(System.in);
}

private void displaySummary() {
    System.out.println("2");
}

private void displayMonth() {
    System.out.println("3");
}

private void findContract() {

    String dDate = "";
    int packG = 0;
    int dBundle = 0;
    int monthS = 0;
    String iCalls = "";
    String rNum = "";
    int mCharge = 0;
    String cName = "";


    Scanner input = null;   // this is to keep the compiler happy
    // as the object initialisation is in a separate block                                             
    try {

        input = new Scanner(new File("archive.txt"));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        dDate = input.next();
        packG = input.nextInt();
        dBundle = input.nextInt();
        monthS = input.nextInt();
        iCalls = input.next();
        rNum = input.next();
        mCharge = input.nextDouble();
        string cName = input.next();

        System.out.println(dDate + "\t" + packG + "\t" +dbundle + "\t" +monthS + "\t" +iCalls + "\t" +rNum + "\t" +mCharge + "\t" +cName);
    }

    input.close();

// end of main
}
    }

}
```

When I select option 4 it displays the following errors:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at contractmanager.Menu.findContract(Menu.java:113)
    at contractmanager.Menu.performAction(Menu.java:68)
    at contractmanager.Menu.runMenu(Menu.java:25)
    at contractmanager.Menu.main(Menu.java:18)
    Java Result: 1
```

Below is the information for ONE contract (each contract is to be displayed like this on a new line):

```
15-Sep-2015 2   1   12  N   MT230N  617 C Mcgee
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the data in the file.  It's not an integer.  You should log each iteration or put a break point in your loop during the execution to see which row has the problem.

From JavaDoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately i'm still quite new to java. 

Would it be possible to show me the correct way to run the while & spit the data out for each contract in the below format.

(The order of the variables in the current while correspond to the order of the information below)

15-Sep-2015 2   1   12  N   MT230N  617 C Mcgee

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `mCharge` is an incorrect type. I'm assuming you want to store it as an `int` based on the variable type and the supplied number, so `nextInt()` is the method you want. If, however, you do want a `double`, then you would change the type of `mCharge` to a double and keep `nextDouble()`. In the case of a double, it will return 617.0 instead of 617. You could convert it to an `int` in that case with something like:

```
int mChargeInt;
if (mCharge == Math.floor(mCharge) && !mCharge.isInfinite()) {
  mChargeInt = (int) mCharge;
}
```

If you ever need to use `mChargeInt`, just make sure that it isn't `null`  first. If it is null, then `mCharge` can be used.

EDIT: It looks like that last part of the string, "C Mcgee", doesn't seem to be formatted properly. The way it is now, `input.next()` would give "C" and not "C Mcgee", which is what I assume is desired.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately i'm still quite new to java. 

Would it be possible to show me the correct way to run the while & spit the data out for each contract in the below format.

(The order of the variables in the current while correspond to the order of the information below)

15-Sep-2015 2   1   12  N   MT230N  617 C Mcgee

Comment: I have it displaying the data by removing the variable assignment just below findContract and just having this in the while loop. 

    while (input.hasNext()) {
            
            String dDate = input.next();
            
                    
            System.out.println(dDate);
        }

Is there any way that you get get it to create a multidimensional array with a new row starting every eighth bit of information until the text file is exhausted?

Comment: That's a different question then the one asked here. I'd recommend you make a new question on SO for that topic.